# segmenting elements in a list and find their statistics

Tags: python, list, nlp, grouping

Can you please help me, how can i solve this problem.

given the following list, i want to find the ENG segments. ENG segments are group ENG elements in the list. I also want to find the segment length,i.e. the number of words in a segment. For example:

```
list1 = ['ENG', 'ENG', 'ENG', 'ENG', 'ENG', 'TSO', 'ENG', 'ENG']
```

in the list we have two ENG segments, i.e.

```
ENG_segments = [['ENG', 'ENG', 'ENG', 'ENG', 'ENG'],['ENG', 'ENG']]
```

ENG segment of length 3: have 3 more or more words

```
length3 = 1
```

segment of length 2: have 2 words

```
length2 = 1
```

segment of length 1: have 1 word

```
length3 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to identify the groups and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the occurrences of the various segments' lengths:

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> import itertools as it
>>>
>>> list1 = ['ENG', 'ENG', 'ENG', 'ENG', 'ENG', 'TSO', 'ENG', 'ENG']
>>>
>>> Counter(min(len([*g]), 3) for k,g in it.groupby(list1) if k == 'ENG')
Counter({3: 1, 2: 1})
```